# Is there any security threat due to advertisements?

Tags: malware, web-browser, spam, incident-response

I was working on my localhost in my computer but I was connected to internet. Recently I downloaded a few music files and since then advertisements are getting popping into my browser through which I downloaded the songs. Advertisements are being shown even if I open a webpage in the localhost. Is there any security threat due to these kind of ads?

Comment: you are getting those ads in the localhost ?

Comment: yeah int the browser in which I downloaded the songs...

Comment: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ALZZx1xmAzg

Answer (score 2):

You've probably downloaded and installed a piece of adware like the Social Search Toolbar or something similar. Such adware are known to force install certain browser addons/extensions/plugins that inject advertisement boxes and/or popups into the webpages you visit.

The good news is that the vast majority of those adware aren't really sophisticated and can be easily removed. Go to your browser's addon's page and try to find anything suspicious then copy the name and try to find removal instructions on Google. For example, there are [tens of results on how to remove the Social Search Toolbar](https://www.google.com/search?q=Social%20Search%20Toolbar).

Comment: Yeah i did something like that. I shall try your solution and get back.

Answer (score 0):

Displaying the advertisements based on the user preference is one of the famous practices followed by the major website networks.

Take **Google** as an example. You will get advertisements on your mailbox that is tailor made for you. It will be based on the searches you made or the mails you receive and the website you visit. They even have included this in their updated policies ans terms.

You case might be related to this scenario. Even though there is not much of a security problem, your *privacy* is questionable.

If you want to prevent this, check whether you are logged in to any websites while surfing. Check the browser settings for any other unwanted toolbars or automatic logged in features. Remove them and make sure you are not connected/logged in any websites that track your history. Cleaning up the browser(history and cache) also comes in handy for an easy fix.

Comment: @TheDownVoter: Please leave a comment. It will help me improve my future answers.

Comment: I am not the  one who downvoted you but I have tried the cleaning of cache but the problem still persists. I guess @Adnan answer may solve the problem. I have to give it a try.

Comment: @BaradwajAryasomayajula Thanks for the response. Please give a comment on How you solved the problem after it is done.

Comment: I tried removing all the plugins but it did not work. It really pissed me off and I reinstalled the browser. I copied the bookmarks folder before reinstalling. Ofcourse that is dumb.

Answer (score 0):

Off-course there is security due to ads, Let me make it clear how the ad provider know about your search and show exact ads while browser which you are searching or have searched for long time ago. This means the ads provider track browsing history, which is a theft by the way. well the good way to be stay protected from the ads is not to visit bogus site while browsing or use a strong system protector application.

However this can be only done by our own mistake, while browsing or surfing net we user click on the ads or install any unwanted application. Let take an real example about Network Performance Ads.

Network Performance Ads is an adware program that show multiple of ads accordingly to your search history. Also Note that this adware program is famously known as adnetworkperformance which display malicious ad on the infected system. 
By visiting the site http://www.adnetworkperformanceremoval.com you will get more information regarding to it.

It comes with free software that can be found and downloaded from the Internet. Unfortunately, some free downloads do not adequately disclose that other software also installed, and you may have installed adware without your knowledge. These ads promote some of additional questionable content including web browsers, optimization tools and other products, according to all adware publisher can generate pay per click revenue. Be very careful what you agree with the installation. Always opt for the custom installation and remove everything that is not familiar, especially optional software that you never want to download and install in the first place. Needless to say that you should not install software that you do not trust.

Answer (score 0):

The advertisement are not harmfull by themselves. The actual problem, is that *something* was installed in your browser without you explicitely allowed it. Said differently your browser is now compromised, because something you do not know and do not manage acts on behalf of you.

In their vast majority, those adware do not cause major harm, but:

- popup windows are annoying
- this wastes network bandwidth
- you could have downloaded a much serious threat

My own conclusion is that your security practices are not on pair with you internet usage. Uncontrolled music servers are known to contain various malwares. If you want to use them, you must strengthen you computer:

- install high quality protection system
- use a non priviledged account
- use a dedicated VM with a snapshot that you reload constently to consult *dangerous* sites

The last way is my prefered one